# What was the significance of 'horns' of the sacrificial altar in Exodus 30?

Tags: hebrews, sin, sacrifice

We read in Hebrews 10:1-4:

> The law is only a shadow of the good things that are coming—not the realities themselves. For this reason it can never, by the same sacrifices repeated endlessly year after year, make perfect those who draw near to worship.  Otherwise, would they not have stopped being offered? For the worshipers would have been cleansed once for all, and would no longer have felt guilty for their sins.  But those sacrifices are an annual reminder of sins.  It is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins.

< Exodus 30 :1-10 reads:

> Make an altar of acacia wood for burning incense.  It is to be square, a cubit long and a cubit wide, and two cubits high—its horns of one piece with it.  Overlay the top and all the sides and the horns with pure gold, and make a gold molding around it..... Once a year Aaron shall make atonement on its horns.

<  My question is : What was the significance of  'horns' of the sacrificial altar in Exodus 30 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Sacrifices**

Note that the word "sacrifices" is plural as per V1, V3 (by pronoun) and V8.  That is, Hebrews 10 is NOT referring to a single sacrifice annually, it is discussing the totality of all of the sacrifices throughout the year, ie, those that occurred:

- on a daily basis, namely the morning and evening sacrifice
- those dedicated to the various annual festival such as Passover & unleavened bread, Pentecost, trumpets, Yom Kippur and Tabernacles.

**Altars**

The original tabernacle/temple of ancient Israel has two altars:

- the bronze altar of burnt offering/sacrifice located in the courtyard, Ex 27:1-8, 38:1-7
- the golden altar of incense located inside the building, Ex 30:1-10, 37:25-29

Sacrifices were ONLY offered on the bronze altar of burnt offering; the Golden altar of incense only had incense burned on it.

**Horns**

Both the bronze altar of burnt offering (Ex 27:2) and the golden altar (Ex 30:2, 3, 10) of incense had "horns".  In both cases, the horns were the most sacred part of each altar.

- in the case of the bronze altar of burnt offering, the blood of the sin offering was applied to the horns, Ex 29:12
- similarly Aaron the High Priest was to make atonement on the horns of the golden altar once per year as follows:

> Ex 30:10 - Aaron shall make atonement on its horns once a year. With
> the blood of the sin offering of atonement he shall make atonement for
> it once in the year throughout your generations. It is most holy to
> the LORD.”

In commenting on this verse, the Pulpit commentary says this:

> **Verse 10. - Aaron shall make an atonement upon the horns of it once in the year.** Once in the year, on the great day of atonement - the
> tenth day of the seventh month - the high priest, after burning
> incense within the veil, and sprinkling the blood of a bullock and a
> ram towards the mercy seat, was to take of the blood, and put it on
> the horns of the altar of incense "to make an atonement for it - to
> cleanse it and hallow it from the uncleanness of the children of
> Israel" (Leviticus 16:18, 19). This was not making it an altar of
> expiation, but merely expiating it. There was, however, another use
> for the altar, where it seems to have served for an altar of
> expiation.

More than this we cannot say because the Bible says nothing, other than the above, about the significance of the altar horns.

However, we could pause to note that the "horn" is sometimes used as a symbol of strength, as per Deut 33:17, 2 Sam 22:3, Ps 18:2.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, Dottard. I have since edited the question to make it more focussed.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan - answer updated

Answer (score 1):

The horns of the altar linked God's provision of earthly sustenance (from above) with humanity's expression of thanksgiving (from below). Bulls and other horned animals were offered on the altar daily, sometimes in great numbers. This tradition was not unique to Israel. Indeed horned altars have been found [throughout the area](https://library.biblicalarchaeology.org/article/four-horned-altar-discovered-in-judean-hills/). Thus, in terms of culture, the significance of the horned altar may not have been a conscious one, but rather represents an inherited tradition from Israel's distant past, first as hunter-gatherers and then as nomadic herdsmen.

[image] *An altar unearthed at Beer Sheba in the* 1970s.

The connection between bulls and the God El, worshiped by both Abraham and Melchizedek (Genesis 14:18), is [well attested in Canaanite religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_(deity)#).

> ʼĒl is repeatedly referred to as "Bull ʼĒl" or "the bull god"... "El"
> (Father of Heaven / Saturn) and his major son: "Hadad" (Father of
> Earth / Jupiter), are symbolized both by the bull, and both wear bull
> horns on their headdresses.

The bull seems to have been a favored animal of Yahweh. In this context, the infamous bull-calves of the northern shrine at Bethel were the idolatrous expression of something the horned altar hinted at: the God of Israel and Judah fed his people with horned animals, providing them not only with meat but also with hides, sinew, wool and milk - key necessities of life in those times. His people in turn offered him the sacrifice of horned animals as a sign of their loving gratitude and loyalty.

[image] *At the temple in Jerusalem, bronze oxen supported the "molten sea" that provided water for the priests. (1 Kings 7:25)*

**Conclusion**: The horns of the altar linked God's provision of sustaining grace with humanity's expression of thanksgiving. They represent a meeting point of God and human beings, heaven and earth. As with Hebrews 10, Psalm 51 recognizes that God does not want the sacrifice of sinners but the sincere offering of a faithful heart, including the sacrifice of horned animals on the horned altar.

Psalm 51

> You do not desire sacrifice or I would give it;
> a burnt offering you would not accept.
> 19 My sacrifice, O God, is a contrite spirit;
> a contrite, humbled heart, O God, you will not scorn.
> 20 Treat Zion kindly according to your good will;
> build up the walls of Jerusalem. 21 Then you will desire the sacrifices of the just,
> burnt offering and whole offerings;
> then they will offer up young bulls on your altar.